# How do I properly configure touch on Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, move

I'm making a game on Unity3D. The cube, as shown in the attached photo, should move to a certain position, I achieved this, but there was a problem when I click on the screen, it moves several positions at once, I tested this situation with Debug. Log (I also attached the photo), and as you can see, with one click, the function is triggered several times, how to fix it?

P.S. Also could advise how to add smoothness of movement of the cube, in a certain coordinate, tried through transform.forward, but couldn't figure out how to stop it at the right coordinate.

[The cube's position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNcnv.png)

[The Message Debug.Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUDW2.png)

```
private void Update()
{
    CubePosUp_Z = transform.position.z - 0.7f;
    CubePosDown_Z = transform.position.z + 0.7f;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.position.y > Screen.height / 2)
        {
            tempUp = 1;
            tempDown = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tempUp = 0;
            tempDown = 1;
        }

        if (tempUp == 1 && tempDown == 0)
        {
            UpTran();
        }
        else if (tempUp == 0 && tempDown == 1)
        {
            DownTran();
        }
    }
}

void UpTran()
{
    Debug.Log("Up");

    if (CubePosUp_Z <= -1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 0, Space.World);
    }
    else if (CubePosUp_Z > -1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, -0.14f, Space.World);
    }
}
void DownTran()
{
    if (CubePosDown_Z >= 1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 0, Space.World);
    }
    else if (CubePosDown_Z < 1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.14f, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you go onto YouTube and watch Brackey's video on touch screen controls

Comment: What exactly are your expectations for the lines `transform.Translate(0, 0, 0, Space.World);` ? What is the use of using an object about a distance of .. nothing? ^^

Answer (score 1):

@TheHotboll Here's your solution :-

```
[SerializeField] float touchForce = 2f;

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            transform.Translate (0f, 0f, touch.deltaPosition.x * touchForce * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

First in the `Update ()` function we check if we are actually swiping or just touching. If we are swiping, then we move the transform using `transform.Translate ()` function on the `World Space`. You can also add conditions and check for `touch.deltaPosition.x`. This will work smoothly. Just try it out.

Comment: Sounds more like OP wants to touch and hold on the upper half of the screen for moving up and the lower half for moving down .. not using the deltaPosition (which is in pixel space so a lot bigger then you think

Comment: @derHugo thanks for this. I didn't knew about it. This was just for basic logic. We can check in which direction has the player swiped and add force using `Rigidbody`.